# MySQLi Prepared Statement not returning any results

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm very new to PHP and MySQL, and I'm having trouble performing a prepared statement.

This query returns data exactly as I expect it to:

```
$result = $con->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="' . $user->user_email . '" LIMIT 1');
```

However, when forming the query into a prepared statement,

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user->user_email);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

I get no results every time. Is there something wrong with the way I'm preparing the statement?

Comment: Execute just executes the query, it returns true of false. Are you saying it's returning false? If not, then you need to fetch data using the [fetch method](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: JFYI, [your trouble with mysqli only begins here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison)

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood what execute() does. I only need to know if a row was found, so $stmt->store_result() and $stmt->num_rows seemed to do the job.